Hotkey to move up and down Bone Parent/Child chain?
I'm learning Blender having spent years in 3Ds Max. I'm used to being able to use the Page Up and Down keys in Max to move up or down the parent chain or hierarchy. Is there a hotkey to do this in Blender? For example, if I select the hand and want to move up to the clavicle.
Thanks!

You need to type the bracket keys, same in Pose mode, you can change the shortcuts if you want (right click on the function):


Thank you so much! I appreciate the help. I really hate that Google's search is so bad now that I couldn't even find a simple answer like this. Your help is much appreciated :)
